# How plot a simple graph one point at a time

Tags: julia

I have some simple code that computes one value at a time. I would like a plot that updates as the code runs. At each iteration I compute a new value for the y-axis called `avesofar`.  I would just like to plot another point at x-index `i` with this new value.

```
using Plots

function hamming4(bits1::Integer, bits2::Integer)
    return count_ones(bits1 ⊻ bits2)
end

function random_strings2(n, N)
    mask = UInt128(1) << n - 1
    return [rand(UInt128) & mask for i in 1:N]
end

function find_min(strings, n, N)
    minsofar = n
    for i in 1:N
        for j in i+1:N
            dist = hamming4(strings[i], strings[j])
            if dist < minsofar
                minsofar = dist
            end
        end
    end
    return minsofar
end

function ave_min(n, N)
    ITER = 100
    strings = random_strings2(n, N)
    new_min = find_min(strings, n, N)
    avesofar = new_min
    # print("New min ", new_min, ". New ave ", avesofar, "\n")
    total = avesofar
    for i in 1:ITER-1
        strings = random_strings2(n, N)
        new_min = find_min(strings, n, N)
        avesofar = avesofar*(i/(i+1)) + new_min/(i+1)
        print("New min ", new_min, ". New ave ", avesofar, "\n")
    end
    return avesofar
end

N = 2^15
n = 99

print("Overall average ", ave_min(n, N), "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update a plot in Plots by appending `!` to the function name. So `plot(x, y)` will create an initial plot with your points, and `plot!(xnew, ynew)` will update the last plot with a new point.

So for your case, just add `plot!(i, avesofar)` inside the loop. As mentioned by @przemyslaw-szufel you would use `scatter`/`scatter!` if you don’t want to connect the points with a line.

Comment: `plot` and `plot!` are used for plotting lines rather than points. In the `Plots.jl` API contrary to `PyPlot.jl` updating the plot requires passing the plot object (see my answer below).

Comment: You don’t need to pass the plot object if the plot you are updating is the currently active plot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you plot one point at a time:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
p = Plots.scatter(; lab="")
Plots.scatter!(p, [1], [2]; lab="point 1")
Plots.scatter!(p, [3], [4]; lab="point 2")
Plots.scatter!(p, [5], [6]; lab="point 3")
```